# Percentile to Z-score in PHP or JAVA

Tags: java, php

I am searching for a way to calculate Z score(z) for a given percentile(p). I found  [this](http://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/analysis/zCalc.html)  site doing such a calculation. They have given a formula for calculating P(Z<=z).

[equation](http://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/figures/cumnorm.png) (sorry, could not post the image due to low repution)

Now i have the value of P(Z<=z) and i tried solving it to find out z, but it was really complex to solve for z.

Is there any function in JAVA or PHP which can do this?? or is there any mathematical way in which we can solve for Z.
(I am considering hard-coding the Z table as my last choice because i have to make some approximations in that case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a (badly documented) [statistics extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php). There's a large number of functions in there that ought to be helpful, but I don't know enough about neither statistics in general or the specific extension to say anything more helpful about it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for this (like I was)...   I translated this function from a JavaScript z-score calculator I found and it does the trick. Simply pass it a value between 0 and 1.

```
function percentile_z($p) {
   $a0 = 2.5066282;
   $a1 = -18.6150006;
   $a2 = 41.3911977;
   $a3 = -25.4410605;
   $b1 = -8.4735109;
   $b2 = 23.0833674;
   $b3 = -21.0622410;
   $b4 = 3.1308291;
   $c0 = -2.7871893;
   $c1 = -2.2979648;
   $c2 = 4.8501413;
   $c3 = 2.3212128;
   $d1 = 3.5438892;
   $d2 = 1.6370678;
      
   $p = abs($p - 0.5);
      
   if($p > 0.42) {
      $r=sqrt(-log(0.5 - $p));
      $z=((($c3 * $r + $c2) * $r + $c1) * $r + $c0) / (($d2 * $r + $d1) * $r + 1);
   }
   else {
      $r = $p * $p;
      $z = $p * ((($a3 * $r + $a2) * $r + $a1) * $r + $a0) / (((($b4 * $r + $b3) * $r + $b2) * $r + $b1) * $r + 1);
   }
   if($p < 0.5) $z = -$z;
   return $z;
}
```